# I am trying to draw a stream function in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, contour

I am using this code snap to draw a stream function

```
[X,Y]= meshgrid(linspace(0,80),linspace(-8,8));
[t]=meshgrid(linspace(0,100));
B=1+0.3*cos(0.9*t);
k=2*phi/10;
low=.1+k.^2.*B.^2.*sin(k.*(X-0.9.*t)).^2;
PSI=-tanh((Y-B.*cos(k.*(X-0.9.*t)))./sqrt(low));
contour(X,Y,PSI,3);
colormap cool
```

I wanted to something like the picture. What I am getting only the current(the sin shape lines) but not the vortex(The rectangular shape).
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to generate the plot using the parameters shown, <strike>but I did not manage to get the "vortex" shapes in the contour plot</strike>. Here is my implementation:

```
len = 200;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(linspace(0,80,len), linspace(-8,8,len));
t = meshgrid(linspace(0,1,len));

a = 1.2;
c = 0.12;
k = 2*pi/7.5;
w = 0.4;
e = 0.3;

B = a + e * cos(w*t);
D = k * (X - c*t);
PSI = - tanh((Y - B.*sin(D)) ./ sqrt(1 + (k * B.*cos(D)).^2)) + c*Y;

figure('Position',[100 100 650 300])
movegui('center')

subplot(211)
contour(X, Y, PSI, 10), ylim([-4.5 4.5])
%colormap cool
xlabel('kilometers'), ylabel('km'), title('Mobility Model')

subplot(212), axis off
text(0.5, 0.5, ...
    {['$\psi(x,y,t) = -\tanh{[ \frac{y - B(t) \sin(k(x-ct))}' ...
    '{\sqrt{1 + k^2 B^2(t) \cos^2(k(x-ct))}} ]} + cy$'];
    '$where\, B(t) = A + \epsilon cos(\omega t)$'}, 'Interpreter','latex', ...
    'FontSize',20, 'Horizontal','center', 'Vertical','middle')
```

[image: matlab_contour_plot]

---

<strike>This leads to me believe that the screenshot you've shown does not exactly match the equation/parameters below it...</strike>

In fact if we look at the surface plot in 3D, you'll find that there is no shape in the curve that would look like those triangles in between the sinusoidals. It's just two almost-flat planes, with a dented drop in between.

Here is the two-dimensional function shown as a surface plot:

```
surf(X, Y, PSI, 'FaceColor','interp', 'EdgeColor','none')
daspect([20 6 1])
axis vis3d, axis tight
box on, grid on, view(140,30)
xlabel X, ylabel Y, zlabel PSI
lighting phong
camlight left
```

[image: surface_3d]

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation but still I need those vortex shape

Comment: @user2487309: ok I see the problem; As I expected, the function equation was not exactly the same as the one shown in the paper screenshot you just posted. There is an added term at the end of `PSI = -tanh(..)+ c*y` which was omitted in the original pic. Also the sine function mentions a variable `s` not `x` in `sin(k*(s-ct))`, I assume that's a typo? Now I don't know what it represents, but you should double-check the equation! Anyway when I add the missing term `c*y`, I'm starting to see the "vortex" shapes you are talking about. I've updated my post...

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thank you so much for an awesome answer